# Allure report is not available when after I close command prompt

Tags: cucumber, allure

I have cucumber TESTNG project and I am running test from the command prompt using below command. After the execution is completed. browser is automatically opened and allure report is generated but once I close the command prompt then allure report is not displayed. Even I went to allure report path and try to to generate from there but no data is displayed. My intention is I want allure report to be generated in some path and should be available permanently unless I delete it manually.

```
call mvn clean

call mvn test -Dcucumber.Options="--plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureReporter"

call allure serve target\allure-results
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-examples-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>BDDFramework</groupId>
    <artifactId>BDDFramework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cucumberFramework</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
         <allure.version>1.5.2</allure.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- These are the allure dependencies -->  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- These are the cucumber dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
             <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                 <version>4.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                 <version>4.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                 <version>4.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
                 <version>4.1.2</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                 <version>1.4</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0-beta</version>
          </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
        
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
        
        

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false </testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!-- src/test/resources/testSuites/testng.xml -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    
                    <argLine>
                     -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                        -Dcucumber.options="--plugin ru.yandex.qatools.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureReporter"
                </argLine>
                    
                </configuration>
                
                <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                
            </plugin>
            
            <!--Needed only to show reports locally. Run jetty:run and
            open localhost:8080 to show the report-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>BDDFramework</projectName>  <!-- Replace with project name -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                            <enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts>
                            <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
                        </configuration>
                        
                
                        
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
            <reporting>
                <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                        <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.6</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </reporting>
    
</project>
```